# Override Spring-Boot's GsonAutoConfiguration with custom Gson

Tags: spring-boot, jersey, gson

Is there a way to override the GsonAutoConfiguration in spring-boot?

I would like to add some typeAdapter to the gson instance.

Preferably using java configurations

I've added the following to the application.properties.
`spring.http.converters.preferred-json-mapper=gson`

and the following class

```
@Configuration
@ConditionalOnClass(Gson.class)
public class GsonConfig {
    @Bean
    public Gson gson() {
        return new GsonBuilder()
            .registerTypeAdapter(DateTime.class, new DateTimeTypeAdapter())
            .setPrettyPrinting().create();
    }
}
```

I am also using Jersey in the mix as well.
So I've also have the following code, which also didn't work.

InternalApplication.java

```
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;
import org.immutables.gson.stream.GsonMessageBodyProvider;
import org.immutables.gson.stream.GsonProviderOptionsBuilder;
import org.joda.time.DateTime;

public class InternalApplication extends Application {

  @Override
  public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
    final Set<Class<?>> classes = new HashSet<>();
    classes.add(TestResource.class);
    return classes;
  }

  @Override
  public Set<Object> getSingletons() {
    final Set<Object> singletons = new HashSet<>();
    singletons.add(new GsonMessageBodyProvider(
            new GsonProviderOptionsBuilder()
                .gson(new GsonBuilder()
                    .registerTypeAdapter(DateTime.class, new DateTimeTypeAdapter())
                    .setPrettyPrinting()
                    .create())
                .lenient(true)
                .build()
        )
    );
    return singletons;
  }
}
```

Comment: I had probably a similar issue before, but cannot really recall it: what does happen if you declare your custom `Gson` bean?

Comment: I've updated the question with some code snippets to demonstrate what i've tried; but it doesn't return the json with the proper datetime converted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since when does Gson have anything to with Jersey in Spring Boot? It doesn't. What you really want to do is first *disable* Jackson (which is the default provider). Then you can register your `GsonMessageBodyProvider`.

Basically all you need to do is exclude the Jackson provider from your Maven/Gradle dependencies, as the Jersey starter pulls it in

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
      <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

And I'm not quite sure why you are using an `Application` class, as Spring Boot doesn't support that for its auto-configuration. You should be using a `ResourceConfig` class

```
@Component
@ApplicationPath("/api")
public class JerseyConfig extends ResourceConfig {
    public JerseyConfig() {
        register(TestResource.class);
        register(new GsonMessageBodyProvider(...));
    }
}
```

Comment: Yup. I've realized that after; but that's pretty much the issue.

Application class was used because I was migrating code from Restlet, and most of the things were setup under jax-rs.